# Are Knowledge skill checks Charisma-based after the Lore Keeper Revelation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, oracle

[Lore Oracles](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/oracle.html) can take a Revelation called **Lore Keeper**:

> *Lore Keeper (Ex)*: Instead of encyclopedic knowledge, you learn most of your information through tales, songs, and poems. You may use your Charisma modifier instead of your Intelligence modifier on all Knowledge checks.

They also have access to a Revelation called **Focused Trance** (emphasis mine):

> *Focused Trance (Ex)*: You can enter a deep meditation, blocking out visual and auditory stimuli and allowing you to concentrate on a single problem, philosophical issue, or memory. This trance lasts 1d6 rounds, during which time you can only take move actions. During this period, you gain a bonus equal to your level on all saves against sonic effects and gaze attacks. When you come out of your trance, **you may make a single Intelligence-based skill check with a +20 circumstance bonus**. You may enter your focused trance a number of times per day equal to your Charisma modifier.

If a Lore Oracle has both of these Revelations, can they use Focused Trance to add the circumstance bonus to a Knowledge check, or is the Knowledge check now a Charisma-based skill check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

They are still **Intelligence-based** skill checks. You simply have the *option* to use your charisma bonus instead of your intelligence bonus.

If, for whatever reason, like being drained of your charisma, you must make a Knowledge check, you can still use your intelligence bonus.

However, if you decide to use **Focused Trance**, you will have to use your Intelligence modifier instead of your Charisma modifier, as that [changes the ability that the skill is based on at the time of the roll](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9tga). Otherwise you cannot gain the +20 bonus from it.

If you decide to use your **Charisma bonus** on a Knowledge check, *that check* is now **Charisma-based**. The skill remains as **Intelligence-based** though.

Comment: This is accurate. You'll notice the words used in Lore Keeper is "You may...". Any situation that you get to pick one of (or simply apply) 2, it retains its original Ability as its 'base'. As such, you (typically) could not use a feat or ability that modified Charisma based skills with your Lore Keeper Knowledge.

Comment: So if the character were to use Focused Trance, they would have to use their Intelligence rather than Charisma as the bonus?

Comment: It is still a Knowledge skill check, so they can use either Intelligence or Charisma.

Comment: If they were using Focused Trance on Appraise or Spellcraft, then they must use the Intelligence bonus.

Comment: It seems i was wrong, this FAQ says otherwise: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9tga